# How to route to a gateway on different subnet?

Tags: routing, route, gateway, subnets

My network is on 10.3.4.x/24, with my router on IP 10.3.4.254. I need to ssh access my server on IP 10.3.4.100 but when I set up the server I forgot that I restricted ssh access to 192.168.x.x IPs only.

Is there a way to access the server via network on Linux?

I would need to put my pc on 192.168.x.x but still communicate to the 10.3.4.254 router.

Comment: Which kind of network are you using? Wired? Wireless? With of without wireless isolation?

Comment: @andcoz my pc is wireless, the server is wired to the router. No isolation

Comment: I don't understand why it's been put on hold, what info do you need? The question is clear.

Comment: The reason is that the question is "too broad". There are too many things that can be the problem. We need many details, some clue to restrict the possibilities.  At the moment, to answer to your question I'd need to write a 200 pages book keeping in account all the things that could be wrong in your configuration. This is a Q&A site not a forum.

Comment: I don't agree on the decision, but I accept and respect it. Why denying the choice to answer to somebody that could have another possible solution? :( Anyway ok, I'll edit the file connecting directly the HDD...

Answer (score 0):

1) Connect a computer directly to server, give it a static 192.168.x.x IP, log in and fix the restriction.

2) Create a network namespace on your PC, start an xterm in the network namespace. Connect up the network namespace via a virtual eth-pair to the main namespace. Add 192.168.x.x addresses on the eth-pair. Enable forwarding in the main namespace. Add a static route to 192.168.x.x on your router. Use `ssh` from the network namespace; it will have source address 192.168.x.x.

(1) is probably simpler.

Comment: I need the second option because the server has a fixed ip on 10.3.4.100 (I'm an idiot), could you explain me how to do it? I never used the "ip route" command on Unix

Comment: Um, as long as the server has a single outgoing network interface with a default route, I'd still try (1) - you don't need broadcasts, so the differing prefix shouldn't matter. Option (3) is "take the harddisk out of the server, connect to a different PC, edit config file". Also simpler than explaining how to use network namespaces and basics of routing...

Comment: I tried (1), it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If your router does not isolate your devices, you can try to add an alias to your pc wireless card.

1. Check your pc wireless network interface name (probably `wlan0`):

   ```
   ip address show
   ```
2. Add a second ip address to your interface:

   ```
   ip address add 192.168.0.100/16 dev wlan0
   ```
3. Check the routing table of your pc:

   ```
   ip address show
   ip route show
   ```
4. Try to ssh to your server. If needed, try using ssh `-b` option:

   ```
   ssh -b 192.168.0.100 user@server
   ```

Note that often I needed to connect both device to the router using a wire even if the router (wrongly?) stated that it was not isolating.

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work. When I try to ssh the server, it hangs without any output, not asking for password. What routing do I need?

Comment: Use `ssh -v ...` to check why ssh hangs. If it hangs on `debug1: Connecting to server [192.168.x.x] port 22.`, you'll have to check you router routing table. Check your router manual.

Comment: Note that I am working on the simple supposition that your server network configuration is correct and compatible with our goals.

Comment: This is what it says, nothing relevant I think: https://privatebin.net/?12f9e73e7c16577a#i2s5EYTANjBMgJRwKOzsuuqNnbsHBySFDehb4AR1x2o=        . I did nothing special on server side, it's just reachable by 192.168.x.x on ssh, no firewalls.